# How to show a validation message for file_field in Rails forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, file-upload, validation

I have a simple model class like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :image

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader #using CarrierWave for image uploading

  validates_presence_of :name, :image
end
```

And a form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I click Submit on the form, a validation message "can't be blank" shows next to the Name input field, but nothing shows for the Image file field. I'd like to show a message like "image file is required" or something; how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your model:

> validates_presence_of :image, :message => "choose the file, dummy!"

in your view you can get your error message like this:

> @task.errors.messages[:image].to_sentence

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to validate "file_fields" in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041086/how-to-validate-file-fields-in-rails-3)

You need to validate any sort of upload content field with the content specific type then throw the error. I recommend using a gem for image uploading.